# Laravel - Scripts in @push Directive Not Available In Parent @stack Directive

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, datatables, laravel-blade

Hi :) This is my first post here so sorry if my question is not very clear; I tried to include everything needed to clarify the issue :)

I have a question about the `@push` and `@stack` directives.

My project has a parent view/layout named `admin.blade.php` and various child views, including one named `datatable.blade.php`.  The second file is used to display a datatable with all users, and this datatable requires some JS script which is unique for this particular file (`datatable.blade.php`) and does not have to be included in other child blade view files.

- In my `datatable.blade.php` (the child view), I have the following:

````
@section('page-content')

... Here I have my page contect (the table which shows all the users registered, and other information) ... 
    
@endsection

{{-- @push directive in the child view, pushing content to the parent/master @stack directive --}}
@push('custom-scripts')
    <script>

    ... My custom JS script here (required by the datatable in the ```page-content``` section above ... 
       
        </script>
@endpush
````

- In my parent view/layout `admin.blade.php`, I included the following `@stack` directive:

```
...
    <!-- theme -->
        <script src="../../../assets/js/theme.js"></script>
        <script src="../../../assets/js/utils.js"></script>
        
    <script src="../../../libs/parsleyjs/dist/parsley.min.js"></script>
        
    {{-- Datatables - Always here as these are common for all datatables, then just add JS script in page-content                           section --}}
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.22/datatables.min.js"></script>

        @stack('custom-scripts')
        
     <!-- endbuild -->
    </body>
</html>
```

- However, when visiting the dashboard, my custom script code in not included in my layout admin.blade.php (parent), leading to missing JS code required by the datatable, which in turn causes the datatable to be displayed incorrectly.
- Upon refreshing the page from my browser, this custom-script JS code script loads as expected, and the code in included in the layout admin.blade.php (parent) - This was also confirmed from the browser's console.

1. Could it be that the original layout/parent without the `custom-script` is being cached, which causes the `@stack` directive to not get the required JS script?
2. In this case, how is the content loaded, and the JS code in the `@push` directive not?

Any siggestions would be greatly appreciated - Thanks! :)

Comment: Welcome to SO ... `datatable.blade.php` it need to extends `admin.blade.php` then it will work

Comment: Hi @KamleshPaul :) Thanks for your response! Laravel's documentation (Blade Templates - https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#defining-a-layout) states that when using the `@extends(' ')` directive, one only has to include the `layouts-folder.layout-name`, without the `.blade.php` extension. In fact, the example they provide uses `@@extends('layouts.app')`. However, I still tried your suggestion but it returned a 500 error **View [admin.blade.php] not found**. Thanks!